# adding additional values on array before inserting to database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, insert

I wanted to add a header to my array before inserting it to my database.
its for my auto-generate username function wherein usernames will go by the account type and followed by their account id

e.g
    `account type = student`
    `account id = 20-1491-1243`
    so the username would be:
    `STUD20-1391-1243`

these are my codes that i used for my model:

```
     `***function add_student($data){

        $insert = array(
                'idno'          =>$data['idno'],
               'f_name'         =>$data['f_name'],
                'm_name'            =>$data['m_name'],
                'l_name'    =>$data['l_name'],
                'birth'    =>$data['birth'],
                'contact_number'    =>$data['contact_number'],
                'email'     =>$data['email'],
                'year'    =>$data['year'],
                'strand'    =>$data['strand'],
                'usertype'  =>'student',
                'username'          => ['STUD']$data['idno'],
                'password'      =>'123456'                    
                );
                $this->db->insert('user',$insert);    
        }***`
```

everything else works, i just cant seem to add the STUD in the beginning of my usernames. right now thats an error because i included ['STUD'] before $data. I am at a complete loss.

Comment: Where do you get ['STUD'] from? I can't see an array with the value stud

Comment: May be you should just Concat `"STUD"` before `$data['idno']` like `"STUD".$data['idno'],`

Comment: $id=$data['idno'];

'STUD'.'$id'.

Comment: can you clear your question more. Please add with what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing contactenation.

Change this line

```
  'username'          => ['STUD']$data['idno'],
```

To this

```
  'username'          => "STUD".$data['idno'],
```

Comment: Dont store redundant data in your table. Store the account type and the id and then use CONCAT to parse them together upon output.

Comment: i'd like to learn more about how to CONCAT.. ive heard of that before but havent been practicing it. any links you can offer me? preferrably youtube. audiovisual experience can really help me alot.